# App showing white blank screen when quitting app with back button after open push notification

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, pusher-js

After launching app from **tapping on push notification**, app is showing white blank screen **when quit app with hardware back button**. Logged react navigation stack but showing only 1 route in the stack.

I've tried to override the back function by using `BackHandler.exitApp()` but getting white screen as well. Same goes to the `launchMode` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Tried all possible types but still getting same behaviour. When launch app normally, this issue doesn't happen. Any idea?

Launch normally:

> Launch -> Go to MainScreen -> Press back button -> Quit app

Launch from push notification:

> Launch -> Go to MainScreen -> Press back button -> Show white screen -> Press back button -> Quit app

```
//App.tsx
<SafeAreaProvider>
   <AuthContext setLoggedInState={setLoggedIn}>
      <NavigationContainer>
         <MainBottomTabNav isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
         <DropdownAlert />
      </NavigationContainer>
   </AuthContext>
</SafeAreaProvider>
```

```
//AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:exported="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Update:**

1. So I tried to remove the myapp `intent-filter`, change to other `launchMode` but still returned white screen.
2. Checked out the adb logcat and notice that `OpenNotificationActivity` is attached before `MainActivity`. Suspecting this was the cause but still not sure how to disable/bypass the [notification activity](https://github.com/pusher/push-notifications-android/blob/master/pushnotifications/src/main/java/com/pusher/pushnotifications/reporting/OpenNotificationActivity.kt) directly to main
3. Tried adding `android:noHistory="true"` to `MainActivity` and error still persist. Added logcat for reference.

Logcat

```
//press back once - show empty screen
2023-01-10 16:46:00.312 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@2bf2385[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme key 0
2023-01-10 16:46:00.542 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@2bf2385[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme key 1
2023-01-10 16:46:00.567 19681-19681/com.myapp D/SensorManager: unregisterListener :: com.facebook.react.common.ShakeDetector@f13d4ca
2023-01-10 16:46:00.568 19681-19681/com.myapp I/PUSHER_WRAPPER: onPause: MainActivity
2023-01-10 16:46:00.581 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@e02686c[OpenNotificationActivity]: stopped(false) old=true
2023-01-10 16:46:00.584 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@e02686c[OpenNotificationActivity]: stopped(false) old=false
2023-01-10 16:46:00.601 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0x7104eed / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1121 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1824 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
2023-01-10 16:46:00.603 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@e02686c[OpenNotificationActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)0 dur=11 res=0x7 s={true -5476376619252260592} ch=true fn=-1
2023-01-10 16:46:00.613 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376623546288864]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.613 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376623546288864]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.613 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376623546335504]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.613 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376623546335504]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.614 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376623546261408]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.614 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376623546261408]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.616 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@2bf2385[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
2023-01-10 16:46:00.641 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@e02686c[OpenNotificationActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
2023-01-10 16:46:00.641 19681-19681/com.myapp D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@a0792d4[OpenNotificationActivity]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.641 19681-19681/com.myapp D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -16711423
2023-01-10 16:46:00.642 19681-19681/com.myapp D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@a0792d4[OpenNotificationActivity]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.642 19681-19681/com.myapp D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -16711423
2023-01-10 16:46:00.642 19681-19681/com.myapp V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.myapp ic=null mNaviBarColor -16711423 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
2023-01-10 16:46:00.643 19681-19681/com.myapp D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2023-01-10 16:46:00.643 19681-19681/com.myapp I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2023-01-10 16:46:00.647 19681-19681/com.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: 'ClientS', fd=171
2023-01-10 16:46:00.647 19681-19681/com.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=163
2023-01-10 16:46:00.660 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376623546263872]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.660 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376623546263872]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.669 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376623546277072]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.669 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376623546277072]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.669 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376623546240816]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.669 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376623546240816]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.968 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376623546329520]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.968 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376623546329520]
2023-01-10 16:46:00.969 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0x4dd8fc / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1121 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1814 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
2023-01-10 16:46:00.969 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0xc5f1f73 / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1121 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1824 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
2023-01-10 16:46:00.970 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@2bf2385[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)8 dur=9 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=true fn=103
2023-01-10 16:46:00.972 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@2bf2385[MainActivity]: stopped(true) old=false
2023-01-10 16:46:00.984 19681-19681/com.myapp I/PUSHER_WRAPPER: onDestroy: MainActivity
2023-01-10 16:46:00.984 19681-19681/com.myapp E/unknown:ReactNative: Tried to remove non-existent frame callback
2023-01-10 16:46:00.986 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@2bf2385[MainActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
2023-01-10 16:46:00.991 19681-19681/com.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'd04450c', fd=168
2023-01-10 16:46:01.028 19681-26631/com.myapp W/unknown:ReactNative: StatusBarModule: Ignored status bar change, current activity is null.
2023-01-10 16:46:01.028 19681-26631/com.myapp W/unknown:ReactNative: StatusBarModule: Ignored status bar change, current activity is null.
2023-01-10 16:46:01.028 19681-26631/com.myapp W/unknown:ReactNative: StatusBarModule: Ignored status bar change, current activity is null.

//press back twice - quit app
2023-01-10 16:46:30.821 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@e02686c[OpenNotificationActivity]: ViewPostIme key 0
2023-01-10 16:46:31.018 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@e02686c[OpenNotificationActivity]: ViewPostIme key 1
2023-01-10 16:46:31.089 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@e02686c[OpenNotificationActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
2023-01-10 16:46:31.116 19681-26629/com.myapp I/ReactNativeJNI: Memory warning (pressure level: TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) received by JS VM, ignoring because it's non-severe
2023-01-10 16:46:31.129 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376623546259120]
2023-01-10 16:46:31.129 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376623546259120]
2023-01-10 16:46:31.130 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376623546216000]
2023-01-10 16:46:31.130 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376623546216000]
2023-01-10 16:46:31.130 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376623546263872]
2023-01-10 16:46:31.130 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376623546263872]
2023-01-10 16:46:31.187 19681-19681/com.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=171
2023-01-10 16:46:31.201 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376623546206672]
2023-01-10 16:46:31.201 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376623546206672]
2023-01-10 16:46:31.459 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376623546209664]
2023-01-10 16:46:31.459 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376623546209664]
2023-01-10 16:46:31.460 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0xae285e1 / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1121 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1814 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
2023-01-10 16:46:31.461 19681-19681/com.myapp I/SurfaceControl: assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0x7104eed / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1121 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1824 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9005 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3360 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2618 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9971 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
2023-01-10 16:46:31.463 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@e02686c[OpenNotificationActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)8 dur=9 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=true fn=2
2023-01-10 16:46:31.464 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@e02686c[OpenNotificationActivity]: stopped(true) old=false
2023-01-10 16:46:31.470 19681-19681/com.myapp I/ViewRootImpl@e02686c[OpenNotificationActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
2023-01-10 16:46:31.474 19681-19681/com.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: '772477 ', fd=134
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two scenarios in which this can happen

1. the `MainScreen` is not defined as lunchable `activity` in `androidManifest` file (so check that out)
2. react native is adding an other activity to open your `MainScreen`

anyways I think the best way is to close the app yourself when user presses the `backButton` in android
you can use this:

```
import React, { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

BackHandler.exitApp();
```

this is for android only

if this didn't help please share your `androidManifest` file here because I am sure the problem is there somewhere

EDIT

based on comments I understand this is happening because

> it seems to be causing from b8ne/react-native-pusher-push-notifications library. I noticed that OpenNotificationActivity is attached before MainActivity. Hence when first backPress is triggered, it's destroying MainActivity leaving white screen from OpenNotificationActivity

so please add `noHistory` attribute to your `MainActivity` in your `AndroidManifest` file for more information please take a look at the [no history flag docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, like I mentioned earlier in my question, I've tried this approach but it's still showing the white screen. I've updated my question with `AndroidManifest.xml` code

Comment: seems like a problem within react native itself, seems like it doesn't understand `android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"` but if you really are curious see what activity appears after back by showing a log after backPress so we can know what is happening exactly

Comment: After checking out the adb logcat, it seems to be causing from `b8ne/react-native-pusher-push-notifications` library. I noticed that `OpenNotificationActivity` is attached before `MainActivity`. Hence when first backPress is triggered, it's destroying `MainActivity` leaving white screen from `OpenNotificationActivity`. But I still have no idea on how to prevent the push notification activity from attaching

Comment: so I will update my answer

Comment: Tried that too but still persist. Added logcat for reference.